# Where does Freemarker load templates in a maven generated jar

Tags: java, maven, freemarker

Let me clarify my current practice. I have a maven project and the package architecture looks like below:
*src/main/java/com/gearon/app/App.java

src/main/java/com/gearon/app/configuration/Config.java

src/main/java/com/gearon/app/datamodel/*.java*

I tried to set directory where to load templates in Config.java with code below:

```
    cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(Config.class, "/templates");
    cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
```

I have put templates under *src/main/java/com/gearon/app/templates*
The architecture is *src/main/java/com/gearon/app/templates/*.ftl*

It works fine if I run the code directly with main method. However, when I package the project into a jar, it fails to load templates and the error looks like below:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "index.ftl" not found.
```

I'd like to know where to put those tempaltes.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you are using an old FreeMarker version (I see it from the error message). Newer ones has more helpful error messages, among others.

Comment: @ddekany Thanks man. I'd like to upgrade it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, based on research on manual from [Freemarker official site](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html)

> void setClassForTemplateLoading(Class cl, String basePackagePath) and
>   void setClassLoaderForTemplateLoading(ClassLoader classLoader, String
>   basePackagePath): These are for when you want to load templates via
>   the same mechanism with which Java loads classes (from the class-path,
>   as they used to say vaguely). This is very likely be the preferred
>   means of loading templates for production code, as it allows you to
>   keep everything inside the deployment jar files. The first parameter
>   decides which Java ClassLoader will be used. The second parameter
>   specifies the package that contains the templates, in /-separated
>   format. Note that if you don't start it with /, it will be interpreted
>   relatively to the package of the Class parameter.

The Note is what matters:

> Note that if you don't start it with /, it will be interpreted
>   relatively to the package of the Class parameter.

After change
 `cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(Config.class, "/templates");`
to
`cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(Config.class, "templates");`

Everything works fine like a charm.